# My code for CS50x Harvard on edX problem set 2 doesn't give back the expected output

Tags: c, cs50, readability

I am taking [CS50x Harvard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CS50) on [edX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdX), and I'm currently working on problem set 2, readability. I've compiled my code, and it should work to determine the reading level like it's supposed to. However, every time I run the program, no matter what I put in it gives back the answer before grade 1.

Where is the error?

Here's the code.

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Get text from user
    string text = get_string("Text:  ");

    // Start words on 1 because theres always 1 less space then words
    int letters = 0;
    int words = 1;
    int sentences = 0;

    // Count characters
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
    {
        // Check for letters
        if (isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            letters++;
        }
    // Check for spaces
        else if (text[i] == ' ')
        {
            words++;
        }
        else if (text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '?' || text[i] == '!')
        {
            sentences++;
        }
    }

    float L = (float)letters / (float)words * 100;
    float S = (float)words / (float)sentences * 100;


    int index = (int)round(0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8);
    if (index > 16)
    {
        printf ("Grade 16+\n");
    }
    else if (index < 1)
    {
        printf ("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("Grade %i\n", index);
    }

}
```

Comment: FYI, there are dozens of universities and colleges.  Each may have a different numbering system for their courses.  Some may have a CS50 class that doesn't match the one you are taking.  I highly recommend adding clarification as to which CS50 class and it's subject matter.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews CS50 is a Harvard self study class. It's known enough on SO to have a tag for it, as you can see on this post.

Comment: You should use `using std::string;` and `using std::cout;` to your program, preferably near the top.

Comment: Simply adding a sample string and the grade you expect it to get would help. At the moment it's obvious that the code could give a result of 'before  grade 1'. What we need is a case where you think that is wrong (plus what you think the grade should be and why).

Comment: @ OP, this looks like an excellent time to learn how to use a debugger. Is `index` the value you expect it to be?

Comment: Your definition of *word* is incorrect.  You are counting the number of spaces.  Text can have multiple spaces between words.

Comment: Okay well this is a paragraph that I know should recieve grade 8 and it says before 1, sorry Im very new so Im just trying to learn I dont know alot, Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in it, "and what is the use of a book," thought Alice "without pictures or conversation?"

Comment: @blackbrandt: it was marked as C++ when I was reading it and adding the comments.

Comment: Sorry its supposed to be c

Comment: `string text` is not C.

Comment: how is it not c they use it in the course as c

Comment: @ThomasMatthews how do I fix this Im really stuck

Comment: @NotaGuruJordan Well here's the problem, by the formulae you have written down in your program the result of 'before 1' is correct. I don't know what the formulas should be but presumably you have made some mistake in translating them into C. Can you provide a reference to the formulae?

Comment: @NotaGuruJordan OK, I guess some magic in <cs50.h> makes it legal C. It is not legal C if you remove that non-standard header.

Comment: @john yes, I've never gone thru cs50 stuff myself, but from previous posts about it on SO, I recall that cs50.h contains a `typedef char* string` or something similar, and I assume the associated `get_string` function does the necessary memory allocation for you.

Comment: @blackbrandt Okay ill try the debugger I dont know how to use it tho will have to learn

Comment: @john yes the formula is 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8, L is the avg number of letters in 100 words and S is the avg number of sentences per 100 words

Comment: @john its called the Coleman-Liau Index

Comment: There is a whole Stack Exchange site dedicated to [Harvard CS50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CS50): *[CS50](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/tour)*. But do check what is on-topic, etc. before posting

Answer (score 0):

You got your formulae for `L` and `S` incorrect

Here's the correct formulae

```
float L = ((float)letters*100) / (float)words;
float S = ((float)sentences*100) / (float)words;
```

*L is the average number of letters per 100 words* and *S is the average number of sentences per 100 words*, reference [here](https://guilherme-pirani.medium.com/cs50x-readability-2bcf3062c8d7).

If you had only printed out the intermediate values of `L` and `S` and compared them to your expectations then you would have seen the error immediately. Learning how to debug your own code is a **vital** skill for a programmer.

Comment: thankyou I really appreciate it, I will start learning how to debug myself